# After adding into script echo file_get_contents(myfile.php) some parts of script myfile.php won't work. Any idea why?

Tags: php, mysql, echo, file-get-contents

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='5' id='row1-info' class='emarNote'>
<div id='odgovor'>

    <form name='form' action='insertodg.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validateForm()' class='odgovor-form frame inbtn rlarge'>
        <input type='text' name='odgovor' placeholder='Odgovorite...' class='odgovor-input'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' />
        <input name='submitodgovor' type='submit' value='Go' class='odgovor-btn' />        
    </form>

</div>
</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The script perfectly work now, but when i exclude whole form outside, and call with `file_get_contents()` it give me an error - something like `myfieldId` can not be null, and is not. I really have no idea what is that?

So if I make like this,

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='5' id='row1-info' class='emarNote'>
echo file_get_contents ("myfile.php");
echo "</td></tr>";
```

FIrst error is  Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\insertfile.php on line 26.
This code is from insertfile.php

```
$sql="INSERT INTO answers 
SET answer = '$_POST[answer]',
user = '$_POST[user]',
questionId = (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE id = '$_POST[id]');

";
```

And second error is  Column `questionId` cannot be null. But when that file wasn't excluded, everything working, and column `questionId` has some values.

Comment: Please show us the code that does *not* work.

Comment: Without the exact error message (containing file and line number) and the corresponding part of the code, it is not possible to tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to include PHP code to execute it is the [`include` construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and related statements:

> The `include` statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

You are using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

> Reads entire file into a string

... and then [echo](http://php.net/echo):

> Output one or more strings

Thus you no longer execute PHP code. You just print strings.